# How can I vary list values in a behavior space experiment in Netlogo?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I have a list of values in my simulation. I would like to vary those values in a behavior space experiment. Is it possible to do that? If so, what is the syntax for doing that in the behavior space experiment? I have not found anything about that in the Netlogo user manual. The user manual only has the syntax for single variable variations.

Comment: Could you give us an example of that list? Or is it a set of variables that you want to covary?

Comment: I have a global variable that is a fixed length list::
set gattr [1 2 3] ; this is done in the setup function
I would like to vary the values in this list for a behavior space experiment. Preferably I would like to be able to vary each element of the list across a range of values with a specified increment like a simple global variable. I have not found a way to do this in the Netlogo user manual.

Comment: Yes, you can. Here's the link to BehaviorSpace documentation: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html

Comment: @umit1010 I don't think that helps here. The documentation does not make any mention of varying lists, only of varying individual values

Comment: @user2253054 Do they have to initially be a list? Could you vary them individually and then put them into a list after varying them?

Comment: Depending on the length of the list, the way the values need to vary, and how many different behaviorspace runs you aim to get, the optimal answer will vary a lot.

Comment: Yes, of course I could do the elements of the list as separate global variables. Makes the code less compact and elegant. You are right about the number of runs issue. I typically do thousands of runs with all the permutations of the variations. So an easy way to specify the variations of the list would simply setting up the experiments. The reason I am using lists is that I use the map function or an anonymous function on the list. This make the code so much cleaner and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to let behaviorspace go through several lists as an option for a variable, but to my knowledge there is no way to do this without having to write out every single list.

```
;in behaviorspace
["the-list" [1 2 3] [2 4 6] [3 6 9]]
```

The easiest solution that doesn't require you to write out every single list yourself, is to just vary the separate values and then combining them afterwards.

```
;in behaviorspace
["item-0" 1 2 3]
["item-1" 2 4 6]
["item-2" 3 6 9]

;in code
set the-list (list item-0 item-1 item-2)
```

A third option would be to generate all the lists you want to go through separately. These can be stored in a txt file, in a csv file, in your netlogo code, as a string in an input field on your interface... and to just use behaviorspace to tell you which of these lists to select

```
;in behaviorspace
["the-index" 0 1 2]

;in code
set the-list-of-lists (list [1 2 3] [2 4 6] [3 6 9])
set the-list item the-index the-list-of-lists
```

And finally, you could choose to use an external option that gives you more control over the Netlogo model inputs like the R-package NLRX. I don't have any personal experience with these options but I assume they can provide you what you need, should you choose to delve deeper into them.